# UPDATE SET coalesce in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this problem in PHP I can't solve:

```
$nIDEmp=$_GET["idEmp"];
$dniEmp=$_GET["dniEmp"];
$sql="UPDATE empleados
  SET
  dniEmp= coalesce($dniEmp, dniEmp) WHERE nIDEmp=$nIDEmp";
```

So, this SQL QUERY **DO** works, I tryied it into my database with no problems, BUT, SQL keeps throwing me the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' dniEmp) WHERE nIDEmp=1' at line 3
```

I just can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I hardcoded NULL into the SQL QUERY and suddenly the code worked
SO, php isn't sending a null value to the sql query?
How do i solve this?

Comment: `var_dump($dniEmp)` and see what you get on that

Comment: @Curious_MInd It just returns `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: after doing the query, check (in PHP) for all the values to be null, if they are null, make the variable = "NULL" like the following:

```
$nIDEmp=$_GET["idEmp"];
$dniEmp=is_null($_GET["dniEmp"])?"NULL":$_GET["dniEmp"]; //<- Here is the solution
$sql="UPDATE empleados
SET
dniEmp= coalesce($dniEmp, dniEmp) WHERE nIDEmp=$nIDEmp";
```